# Java - Strange Behavior of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

--- Thanks a lot for the comments and the hints you left! I solved my problem! ---

I ve got a question, here my Java Code:

```
    ArrayList<Row> row = getARowList();
    while (data.readRecord()) {
        double houseId = data.getSomething();
        int buildTime = data.getSomethingElse();
        for (Row row : rows) {
            // !!!!!!
            row.setAge("DefaultValue"); // !!!!
            // !!!!!**
            if (row.getID() == houseId) {
                if (buildTime < 2009 && buildTime > 1000) {
                    if ((2009 - buildTime) > 30) {
                        row.setAge("OLD");                          

                    } else {
                        row.setAge("NEW");

                    }
                } 
            }
        }

    }

    for (Row row : rows) {
        System.out.println("Strange Thing: " + row.getAge());
    }
```

If I run this, i get the Output:
Strange Thing: DefaultValue
Strange Thing: DefaultValue
Strange Thing: DefaultValue
Strange Thing: DefaultValue
Strange Thing: DefaultValue
Strange Thing: DefaultValue
Strange Thing: NEW

If I delete the line between the "!!!!!" (row.setAge("DefaultValue");) then the result is:
Strange Thing: OLD
Strange Thing: OLD
Strange Thing: NEW
Strange Thing: null
Strange Thing: OLD
Strange Thing: null
Strange Thing: NEW

just for example.
The last one is that what I want. I just want to replace the "null"s by "DefaultValue". But when I set the default value before (see "!!!!!!") the result is wrong, and all values except of the last value have the value "DefaultValue".

Does anybody have an explanation for that? I'm sitting here for 2 hours and I can bassically not understand whats wrong.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Learning to use the basics of a debugger takes less than 2 hours.

Comment: You're modifying the state of the reference. This is nothing strange. The strange thing is that you have to write a Q/A instead of using a debugger.

Comment: You're also using `==` on floating point.

Comment: How does this compile? Multiple variables named row, one named rows with no declaration.

Comment: Why are you using a double to house an ID? Generally, you would use a long (the de-facto standard for IDs). You cannot guarantee equality in the statement row.getID() == houseId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the for loop, why don't you just say

```
if (row.getAge() == null)
    row.setAge("DefaultValue");
```

?  That will only set the nulls to "DefaultValue".  Make sure you remove the code surrounding the ! too

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in an if condition.

```
if(row.getAge() == null){
  row.setAge("DefaultValue");
}
```

Should serve the logic you want.